# R-package missing functions, but has documentation

Tags: r

My problem is when i build a package using devtools, or R CMD INSTALL -build  the package builds, but when I install the resulting .zip (when I've tried binary builds) or .tar.gz
the functions in the package don't show up. I can SEE the functions in the .tar.gz when I unzip and the files are sufficiently large so as not to empty.  ANY help appreciated.

what I'm using: Rstudio, R v 3.1.0

```
>install.packages("E:/R/Rpackage_meadq/meadq_1.0.4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
'\\AA.AD.EPA.GOV\ORD\RTP\USERS\A-D\dhall05\Net MyDocuments'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'meadq' ...
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
* DONE (meadq)
>installed.packages()
...
meadq         "3.1.0"
> library('meadq')
>ls('package:meadq')
character(0)
## to take an example function within package
> create_ont_csv()
Error: could not find function "create_ont_csv"
>?create_ont_csv
```

this pulls up the function documentation for `create_ont_csv` that's in the package

when I look at the "meadq_1.0.4.tar.gz" using winzip, I can see all the functions.
I've tried building in binary and the same thing happens where the functions are missing, but the documentation is there.

I've tried re-building a lot with this code and also `R CMD INSTALL -build ...` :

```
> library('devtools')

Attaching package: ‘devtools’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:utils’:

    ?, help

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    system.file


> build("E:/R/Rpackage_meadq/meadq")
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD build "E:\R\Rpackage_meadq\meadq"  \
  --no-manual --no-resave-data 

* checking for file 'E:\R\Rpackage_meadq\meadq/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* preparing 'meadq':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
* building 'meadq_1.0.4.tar.gz'

[1] "E:/R/Rpackage_meadq/meadq_1.0.4.tar.gz"
```

Comment: It took me a little work, but I actually found **meadq** on github. Is it your package, or are you just trying to use it?

Comment: whats's in the namespace file? can you access the functions with `meadq:::function_name`?

Comment: @rawr I shouldn't waste your time, the link is [here](https://github.com/dianaransomhall/meadq). As far as I can tell, none of the functions are exported. That's why I was trying to determine if this was their package or not...

Comment: thank you for your response! I didn't get notified that anyone answered. I will look into function exporting and see if that worked.

Comment: i forgot to mention that it is my package.  I don't understand how to edit the namespace

Comment: ok, I got it to work by changing the namespace file. the issue was I used exportPattern that was excluding "." files, but many of my function names contained ".", I changed exportPattern to include anything with letters and that's worked.